# why I am still getting firestore data from production when performing testing using emulator?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am using

- Node 14
- firebase functions-test: 0.2.3
- firebase-admin: 9.6.0
- firebase-functions: 3.13.2
- firebase tools: 9.10.0

I am trying to perform unit testing of my scheduled cloud function. my cloud functions is like this

```
export const deleteExpiredEvents = functions
.pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *") 
.timeZone("Asia/Jakarta")
.onRun(async (context) => {

    // delete expired events


});
```

I test the function above like this

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as firebase from "firebase-functions-test";

const test = firebase({
  databaseURL: "https://xxxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: projectID,
}, "./service-account.json");

const db = admin.initializeApp().firestore();

beforeEach( async () => {
    // create dummy expired event
   
    await db.doc(`events/${event1.eventID}`).set(event1);
    await db.doc(`events/${event2.eventID}`).set(event2);
    await db.doc(`events/${event3.eventID}`).set(event3);
});

it("should not delete events that not expired", async () => {
 
     const wrap = test.wrap(myFunctions.deleteExpiredEvents);

     const context = {};  
     wrap(context); // execute function
        
     const querySnapshot = await db.collection("events").get();
     querySnapshot.docs.forEach((snapshot) => console.log(snapshot.data().eventID));
        
     // the rest of my code test ....
});
```

as you can see from the code above, in `before` block, I try to create dummy event data, so I expect my firestore emulator will be populated with these 3 dummy event data.

and then in the `it` block, I try to get all events and then `console.log` all the `eventID`s

I expect I will get 3 events from firestore emulator that previously created in the `before` block, but I don't know why I get 74 events (instead of just 3), and it comes from firestore production data, not from firestore emulator

I believe I already run `firebase emulators:start` , firestore, functions and pubsub emulators was running when I executed the test.
[image]

so why I am still getting firestore data from production when emulators has been started?

I try to read the documentation from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore

it is said:

> The Firebase Admin SDKs automatically connect to the Cloud Firestore
> emulator when the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable is set:
>
> export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8080"

so I run

```
export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8080"
```

and then

```
firebase emulators:start
```

it still get the data from production. in fact, if I disconnect from the internet, the test will not run!

I don't know why if check

```
console.log(process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST); // I expect, it will be will be "localhost:8080"
console.log(process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR); // I expect, it will be "true"
```

but I will get `undefined` for both values, like this

[image]

Comment: Are you telling the Firestore SDK to `useEmulator` anywhere as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited my question above, to include the result after read that documentation. I have tried to use export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8080" in terminal before executing `firebase emulators:start` but it still connect to the production. in fact, if I disconnect from the internet, the test will not run!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am using admin SDK, so `useEmulator` doesn't exist

Comment: @AgungLaksana yup, check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after updating to the latest firestore emulator (v1.11.14.jar)
[image]

I think I find this solution

1. run your simulator as usual using `firebase emulators:start`
2. in your terminal, run

`export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8080"` (for mac)

`set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8080"` (for windows)

3. run your test as usual.

Answer (score 0):

after reading [github issue in here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/issues/94#issuecomment-533066616). I finally find the solution!

first, in your package.json , write your test script. my script is like this

```
"scripts": {
    "test-security-rules": "mocha -r ts-node/register src/tests/firestore_security_rules_tests --recursive --extension .test.ts --timeout 60000 --exit",
    "test-cloud-functions": "mocha -r ts-node/register src/tests/cloud_function_tests --recursive --extension .test.ts --timeout 60000 --exit"
  }
```

turn off your emulators, and don't run `firebase emulators:start`
. but execute

`firebase emulators:exec "npm run test-cloud-functions"`

and then if you print

```
console.log(process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST);
```

that value will no longer undefined, but it will be `"localhost:8080"` in my case

here is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype#automate_your_tests_with_custom_scripts) about `exec`