# React native app with firestore-emulator. Queries getting firestore-production data mixed with firestore-emulator data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

Sample Code of assigning emulator ports

`authstore.js`

```js
import firebase from "@react-native-firebase/app";
import "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import "@react-native-firebase/firestore";
import { FirebaseAuthTypes } from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
if (__DEV__) {
    firebase.firestore().useEmulator('localhost', 8080);
    firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://127.0.0.1:9099');
}
```

Now when I query my business data

```js
const data = await firebase.firestore()
                .collection('business')
                .where('clients', 'array-contains', 'client1')
                .get();
```

I am getting two documents say `ABC` and `XYZ`. But I have only one document in firestore emulator database ie. `ABC`. I have one document in firestore production database `XYZ`. Why I am getting both?

Comment: can you check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#disable_and_enable_network_access), disable network access for your Cloud Firestore client. While network access is disabled, all snapshot listeners and document requests retrieve results from the cache.

Comment: This should be mentioned in emulator documentation as well as it not expected behaviour.

Comment: can you check if you are using the correct ports for the emulator and configured correctly.

Comment: I am also getting the emulator data. so the port should be correct right?

Comment: can you check the suggestions in this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67033084/why-i-am-still-getting-firestore-data-from-production-when-performing-testing-us) and [github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/issues/94#issuecomment-533066616)